# How to use setState with nested JSON array object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get data from MongoDb, but setState not updating **bookInstances**

How can I use setState to update bookInstances? and each array is basically like {"id": ...}

```
export default class BookInstances extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.BookInstance = this.BookInstance.bind(this);
    this.BookInstances = this.BookInstances.bind(this);
    this.state = {
        bookInstances: []
    }
}

componentDidUpdate() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3001/catalog/bookinstances')
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({ bookInstances: res.data });
        })
}

BookInstance(props) {
    return <li>{props.bookInstance}</li>
}

BookInstances() {
    const bookInstances = this.state.bookInstances;
    if (bookInstances) {
        return bookInstances.map(bookInstance => {
            return <this.BookInstance key={bookInstance} bookInstance={bookInstance.id} />
        })
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Book Instance List</h1>
            <ul><this.BookInstances /></ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

Appreciate any assistance ?

Comment: Go through this article https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/fetching-data-updating-state-react-class

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you'd use a class component nowadays.. Nonetheless, you're setting state in the wrong lifecycle method.

You'll need to fetch within `componentDidMount()`

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3001/catalog/bookinstances')
        .then(res => {
            this.setState({ bookInstances: res.data });
        })
}
```